# Increment database values using "update" and "join" together in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

My code isn't working. I've tried a few different thing but am not sure where to go from here. I'm adding to values that begin from null in the following query. After I run my code, the score values are still null.

The Answers database and the WeeklyPredictions database both have several attributes for additional questions in them. This is just a snippit of code using the first Question 1.

```
    var Q1 = "";
    var weeknumber = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {
        if (Request.Form["weeknumber"] != null)
        {
            weeknumber = Request.Form["weeknumber"];
        }
        if (Request.Form["Question1"] != null)
        {
            string selectedAnswer = Request.Form["Question1"].ToString();
            Q1 = Request.Form["Question1"];
        }


        var db = Database.Open("foo");

        var q1w = ("UPDATE t1 " +
            "SET t1.weeklyScore = t1.weeklyScore + 10, t1.totalScore = t1.totalScore + 10 " +
            "FROM dbo.Scores as t1 " +
            "INNER JOIN dbo.WeeklyPredictions AS t2 " +
            "ON t1.Id = t2.Id " +
            "WHERE t2.Question1 = @0 " +
            "AND t2.WeekNumber = @1");

db.Execute(q1w, Q1, weeknumber);
```

Comment: The syntax of the SQL seems OK, so my guess would be a problem with your variable assignment. Can you run the SQL in SSMS manually (using a specific Question1 value and WeekNumber value)? What happens?

Comment: Hi, I don't have SSMS...maybe I will download it. I know that I have values in the WeeklyPredictions database that will work to add points to the user score. Still, the scores are null. I can see the database design and I can see what's in the tables @Aron

Comment: You don't have to use SSMS (although I think it makes things easier), maybe you could execute the ASP code with a hardcoded value. Just to isolate where the issue is. is `weeknumber = Request.Form["weeknumber"];` the exact same data type as the table? are there any padded spaces or characters? the SQL statement requires an exact match. Just throwing it out there ,since I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Aron thanks. the values are correct since all that can be submitted through the form are pre-set values that correspond to the chosen radio button. I hard coded "0" and found out that the value just can't be null. I can't add 10 to null

Answer (score 2):

In SQL `NULL + 10` is still `NULL`, change your code to use `ISNULL(col, 0) + 10`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Okay, this was the problem. I hard coded "0 + 10" and it saved 10 to the database. I can't figure out how `ISNULL` or `IFNULL` work though. I tried doing: `IFNULL(t1.weeklyScore, 0))` as well as `ISNULL(t1.weeklyScore, 0))` and the functions weren't recognized. For reference, my error was - **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: 'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

Comment: @JulesMena Can you post in your question the new code you've tried which gave you this error?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is SQL Server, I would write this as:

```
UPDATE s 
    SET weeklyScore = COALESCE(s.weeklyScore, 0) + 10,
        totalScore = COALESCE(s.totalScore, 0) + 10 
FROM dbo.Scores s INNER JOIN
     dbo.WeeklyPredictions wp
     ON s.Id = wp.Id 
WHERE wp.Question1 = @0 AND wp.WeekNumber = @1;
```